# Approved review not showing on product view page on frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-review

Blank div showing with no content

```
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
```

But the review form working fine.
What is the issue? Any solution for this?

Comment: have you check rating option is save `store view`. e.g. price should be save in all store view. http://prntscr.com/ntwb3f

Comment: yes  correct store selected but not showing again

Answer (score 2):

Another option Add the below code in Add this div in /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

```
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock("Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView")
        ->setTemplate("Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml")
        ->toHtml();
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The review will be loaded via Ajax `review/product/listAjax`. So, you need to debug the controller:

`vendor/magento/module-review/Controller/Product/ListAjax.php`

JS logic:

`vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js`

Make sure the review is approved and the review config is enabled: **STORES > CATALOG > Catalog > Product Review**

Magento ver. 2.3.1

Comment: hi @Khoa, In my case there are 8 reviews for a product they are showing in tab but summary is empty, can you help me with that pls

Comment: Same issue. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the below code in `catalog_product_view.xml`.

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="product.info.details" />
```

just change

```
"reviewsTabSelector": "#tab-label-reviews"
```

to

```
"reviewsTabSelector": ".column.main"
```

in `Magento_Review/templates/review.phtml`

Make `trigger click` on the first tab by jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 4000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 6000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the below code in `catalog_product_view.xml`.

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="product.info.details" />
```

just change

```
"reviewsTabSelector": "#tab-label-reviews"
```

to

```
"reviewsTabSelector": ".column.main"
```

in `Magento_Review/templates/review.phtml`

Make trigger click on the first tab by jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 4000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#tab-label-description').trigger('click'); }, 6000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Override the below file and replace the code.**

*vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js*

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @param {String} url
     * @param {*} fromPages
     */
    function processReviews(url, fromPages) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            showLoader: false,
            loaderContext: $('.product.data.items')
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#product-review-container').html(data).trigger('contentUpdated');
            $('[data-role="product-review"] .pages a').each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).click(function (event) { //eslint-disable-line max-nested-callbacks
                    processReviews($(element).attr('href'), true);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }).always(function () {
            if (fromPages == true) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#reviews').offset().top - 50
                }, 300);
            }
        });
    }

    return function (config) {
        var reviewTab = $(config.reviewsTabSelector),
            requiredReviewTabRole = 'tab';
            processReviews(config.productReviewUrl, location.hash === '#reviews');
        if (reviewTab.attr('role') === requiredReviewTabRole && reviewTab.hasClass('active')) {
            processReviews(config.productReviewUrl, location.hash === '#reviews');
        } else {
            reviewTab.one('beforeOpen', function () {
                processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
                var anchor, addReviewBlock;
                event.preventDefault();
                anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
                addReviewBlock = $('#' + anchor);

                if (addReviewBlock.length) {
                    $('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) {
                        if (this.id == 'reviews') {
                            $('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
                        }
                    });
                    if(anchor == 'reviews') {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: addReviewBlock.offset().top - 50
                        }, 300);
                    }
                    else{
                         $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: addReviewBlock.offset().top - 50
                        }, 300);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
});
```